# Flex Deep Linking, and Named Anchor Links

Tags: apache-flex, anchor, deep-linking

OK deep-linking in flex uses the anchor(#) text in the URL. So a link to a named anchor on the same page would override the anchor text used by Flex and reset the application. Does anyone know of a way they can coincide?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this [issue](https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-9722).

> DeepLinking behaves oddly when using named anchors in an HTML page [...]

A full list of issues can be found [here](http://labs.adobe.com/wiki/index.php/Flex_3:Feature_Introductions:_Deep_Linking).

[UrlKit 0.5](http://joeberkovitz.com/blog/2006/09/22/urlkit-05-hits-the-streets/) may be of interest if you intend to use this feature.